# flex video player doesn't play until the video is fully loaded

Tags: apache-flex, video

the player uses a VideoDisplay
and i set the source like videoDisplay.source = "sourceStringURL"

and the vid doesn't play until it's fully loaded

Comment: video format, your player's buffertime/buffersize etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to play recorded MP4 then it will not play until you record it in Progressive format, and if you cant specify progressive format then you have to use this program [QTIndexSwapper](http://renaun.com/blog/2007/08/22/234/) that will help you.

When you directly record MP4 format, the file size is unknown for the recorder so when you stop recording the recorded moves the MOOV atom which is beginning point of MP4 at the end of the file. This atom needs to be placed at the beginning for flash player to detect its length and where to start. QTIndexSwapper does it for you. You will also get lots of c based program to do that.

Comment: i  made the mp4 clips through sony vegas, i don't know if they are in progressive format

Comment: Then try QTIndexSwapper and see if it helps or not, if its not progressive , this program will make it progressive.